# C# PictureBox variable in a class

Tags: c#, variables, picturebox

I was trying to make a struct with 2 variables, Double and PictureBox. People suggested that I should use class instead of struct. When I try to create the class. It won't let me add `PictureBox card;` it's just underlining it red.
Any solution or reason why? or suggestion to how I can do. I just need a variable, that can hold picturebox and a double. So I can use it as an array.

Comment: are you missing an import? what does the error message say when you hover over the underlined text?

Comment: What error message are you getting? Probably you're missing a using statement and maybe a reference

Comment: I got "using System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox;" and it says that i'm type or name space 'PictureBox' could not be found

Comment: Only put using  System.Windows.Forms;  then you will be able to use PictureBox card;

Comment: @GK28 I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class would be easier, and I would also recommend using a `List` instead of `array`. Example:

```
    class Container
    {
        public PictureBox picture { get; set; }
        public double number { get; set; }
    }

    List<Container> PicturesAndNumbers = new List<Container>();
```

To add things to the list you will need to make a method:

```
    public void AddToList(Container ContainerToAdd)
    {
        PicturesAndNumbers.Add(ContainerToAdd);
    }
```

Which you can then call like this:

```
    Container NewContainer = new Container();
    AddToList(NewContainer);
```

For this you will need to reference `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: first time using a container, how do I add stuff to container? NewContainer.picture = pb; doesn't work

Comment: Container is just the name I gave to the class to indicate it contains the variables you wanted to pack together. You can use `NewContainer.picture.image` or `NewContainer.picture.ImageLocation` to set the image. I made a small error in my answer which I will correct now: the properties of class `Container` should be made `public` before you can set them.

Answer (score 1):

Only put using  System.Windows.Forms;  then you will be able to use PictureBox card;

You should also use a class not a struct. See the guidelines on when to use a struct vs class.